# Use of criteria filter on the subscribe platform events

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, platform-event

We are starting to see a high utilization of daily delivered platform events.

We are looking for ways to lower the daily delivered platform event limit. One of the solutions will look into using a criteria filter on the subscribe platform events. We have not seen much documentation on what adding a criteria filter to the subscription can do.

I looked here and I could not find anything about the use of criteria filter:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe.htm

Can you provide us with documentation on adding a criteria filter?

Here is the example that we are using:

```
// Define the subscription criteria
const platformEventName = 'My_Platform_Event__e';
const channelName = '/event/' + platformEventName;
const criteria = {
recordTypeId: {
$in: ['012xx0000000000AAA', '012xx0000000000BBB']
}
};

// Subscribe to the platform event with the criteria
subscribe(channelName, -1, (event) => {
// Handle the received event
console.log('Received event: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
}, criteria)
.then(response => {
console.log('Subscribed to channel ' + channelName);
})
```

Comment: and this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filter_section.htm doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @cropredy We want to implement the similar functionality, however in the link which you provided I do not see any examples or at least any 'hints' how to do it. Could you please help ?

Comment: Amer Bearat, were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys - see answer

Answer (score 1):

This [Add a Filter with the Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filter_tooling_api_add_filter.htm) page goes through the steps. There's no UX to do this.

1. Add a `PlatformEventChannel`

   ```
    /services/data/v59.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel

    {
     "FullName": "MyChannel__chn",
     "Metadata": {
     "channelType": "event",
     "label": "MyCustomPlatformEventChannel"
     }
    }
   ```
2. Add a `PlatformEventChannelMember` that serves as a junction between the `xxx__e` and the custom channel `xxx__chn`

   ```
   /services/data/v59.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember

   {
    "FullName": "MyChannel_chn_MyPlatformEvent_e",
    "Metadata": {
    "eventChannel": "MyChannel__chn",
    "filterExpression": "myFilterExpression",
    "selectedEntity": "MyPlatformEvent__e"
    }
   }
   ```

Where

- `myFilterExpression` conforms to the [Filter Expression doc spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filter_expression_format.htm)

**Notes**

From the OP, it looks like you want to filter on `recordTypeId` but Platform Events don't have record types. You need to filter on values of Checkbox, Date, Datetime, Number, Text and Text Area (long) fields of the Platform Event. [Field Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filter_considerations.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot, we actually want to Filter dynamically by Custom Field called "Location Id" which will be added to our Custom Platform Event. Each our user will be assigned to some Location. Is there a way to dynamically use the filterExpression for a user who opens the LWC when we subscribe to channel ?

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys - I suggest you ask a new question on this site as your use case is different than the original poster. It will then get more attention. Please note  [ask] to get the best response.